# How to scan RSSI of the routers using raspberry pi and python and also sorted them according to the value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

how to scan the RSSI value using the python code and sort out the value according to the RSSI over raspberry pi?
Actually, I want to scan the wifi router RSSI around me and according to RSSI value, all the signal will be sorted. like this photo.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UP6D3.png)